# NSMutableDictionary in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary

After adding the key value pairs in NSMutableDictionary, when i retrive the key/values from it, will that retrived key/value be removed from NSMutableDictionary? or is it stil maintained in NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using *objectForkey* to retrieve the value, the key/value will stay in the dictionary.  If you would like to remove an object for a particular key from the dictionary, you need to use *removeObjectForKey*.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you call removeObjectForKey or similar, it stays in there.